# Asking a new question prefills with previous question's content

Tags: bug

When I try to ask a new question everything is prefilled with my previous questions content. This is new as of today. Bug?

---

UPDATE:
I tried a forced refresh of the page and still the same issue. I then deleted the previous content, submitted a new question, and now when I go to ask a new question it does NOT pre-fill with the previous questions content. Maybe an intermittent issue with this application saving questions every XX seconds? At any rate it does not appear to be persisting.

Answer (score 2):

If you leave a question or answer filled in but don't submit, it will often be saved until you return. See [this meta post on saving drafts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting) for more details.

Comment: I submitted my previous question so this must be a bug.